# TLE in FOXLINGS SPOJ

Tags: java, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

> Problem Statement: [FOXLINGS](https://www.spoj.com/problems/FOXLINGS/)
>
> It’s Christmas time in the forest, and both the Fox and the Wolf
>   families are celebrating. The rather large Fox family consists of two
>   parents as well as \$N\$ (\$1 \leq N \leq 10^9\$) little Foxlings. The
>   parents have decided to give their children a special treat this year
>   – crackers! After all, it’s a well-known fact that Foxen love
>   crackers.
>
> With such a big family, the parents can’t afford that many crackers.
>   As such, they wish to minimize how many they give out, but still
>   insure that each Foxling gets at least a bit. The parents can only
>   give out entire crackers, which can then be divided and passed around.
>
> With this many children, not all of them know one another all that
>   well. The Foxlings have names, of course, but their parents are
>   computer scientists, so they have also conveniently numbered them from
>   \$1\$ to \$N\$. There are \$M\$ (\$1 \leq M \leq 10^5\$) unique two-way
>   friendships among the Foxlings, where relationship \$i\$ is described by
>   the distinct integers \$A_i\$ and \$B_i\$ (\$1 \leq A_i,B_i \leq N\$),
>   indicating that Foxling \$A_i\$ is friends with Foxling \$B_i\$, and vice
>   versa. When a Foxling is given a cracker, he can use his tail to
>   precisely split it into as many pieces as he wants (the tails of Foxen
>   have many fascinating uses). He can then pass these pieces around to
>   his friends, who can repeat this process themselves.
>
> Input
>
> Line 1: 2 integers, \$N\$ and \$M\$
>
> Next \$M\$ lines: 2 integers, \$A_i\$ and \$B_i\$, for \$i=1\ldots M\$
>
> Output
>
> A single integer – the minimum number crackers must be given out, such
>   that each Foxling ends up with at least a small part of a cracker.

From the question I attempted with disjoint sets. I applied union by size along with path compression. But the constraints are very high and I could not think how to optimize this further. Offcourse I am getting TLE with solution upon submitting. So can anyone tell me any trick or idea regarding optimization?

```
public static void main(String[] argh) throws Exception{
        // BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Reader br= new Reader();
        int n= br.nextInt();
        int m= br.nextInt();
        int[] dj= new int[n+1];
        int[] size= new int[n+1];
        for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
            dj[i]= i;
            size[i]= 1;
        }
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map= new HashMap<>();
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
            int n1= br.nextInt();
            int n2= br.nextInt();
            union(dj, size, n1, n2);
        }

        for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
            findParent(dj, i);
        }

        for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
            if(!map.containsKey(dj[i])){
                count++;
                map.put(dj[i], 1);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(count);
    }

    private static int findParent(int[] arr, int pos){
        if(arr[pos] == pos) return pos;
        return arr[pos]= findParent(arr, arr[pos]);
    }

    private static void union(int[] arr, int[] size, int pos1, int pos2){
        int posP1= findParent(arr, pos1);
        int posP2= findParent(arr, pos2);

        if(posP1 != posP2){
            if(size[posP1] < size[posP2]){
                int temp= posP1;
                posP1= posP2;
                posP2= temp;
            }
            arr[posP2]= posP1;
            size[posP1] += size[posP2];
        }
    }
```

> Note: Reader is just another fast inputting

Comment: One who negates . Pls do mention reason.

Comment: Have you tested it? Are you aware there's a lot of looping going on?

Comment: The code is correct for small N, for big N I learnt new technique dynamic DSU

Comment: With the same code We cannot go for high N. So I was getting tle

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
    findParent(dj, i);
}

for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
    if(!map.containsKey(dj[i])){
       count++;
        map.put(dj[i], 1);
    }
}
```

This part is slow and unnecessary - you can count how many times you did union instead.

```
 int[] dj= new int[n+1];
```

With 10^9 limit for N, only that line requires 4GB of RAM, when limit for task is 1.5GB. Use HashMap instead and store only unioned ids - there will be at most 2*M of those.

Comment: Yes I found that was consuming lot of space and is not suitable for high N